# How to save measuring data in Java in a easy way?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I think that is a problem which is easy to solve. But somehow I don't find a solution.

I got three type of measurements (in Strings)

```
String watt, ampere, volt;
```

Every timestamp contains an unknown amount of measurements.

I want to save the data (watt, ampere, volt) in a timestamp and save all timestamps in a set of all data.

So I want to access my data in a similar way:

```
setOfAllData.get("this timestamp").get("FIRST measurement (watt, ampere, volt)");
setOfAllData.get("same timestamp as above").get("SECOND measurement (watt, ampere, volt)");
```

It is a bit hard to explain, but I hope it is understandable what I mean and I am thankful for your help. This should be coded in Java.

Comment: So you want a Map<Timestamp, List<Measurement>>? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: You should look into Java's Collections Library, there's lots of great tools and data structures. a Map is what I think you're looking for

Comment: Oh wow. Never used Maps. But that looks helpful. I will try it out later. I guess this is the solution for my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Questioner123123 Using `Map` and other collections is basic stuff in Java. I suggest you spend some time studying the [Oracle Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), specifically  the [one on collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class for `Measurement` with three member variables for your three electrical readings. (By the way, use appropriate data types such as `BigDecimal` or `Double` rather than making everything `String`.)

Collect related `Measurement` objects into a list, `List< Measurement >`.

Attach that list to a key value for insertion into a `Map`. The key represents a timestamp. I assume you will use `java.time.Instant` for those timestamp values. So your map will be a `Map< Instant , List< Measurement > >`.

```
Map< Instant , List< Measurement > > map = new TreeMap<>() ;
```

Mapping a key to a list in Java has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.